# Can I use LDAP to lookup user authentication events?

Tags: ldap

Specifically I want to know the hostname that users are logging in from. Is this possible using an LDAP query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP is a directory tool. At most you *might* be able to look up the last date, time and client for someone signing in. I'm not familiar with anyone actually implementing this.

What you really would want would be the log history (security event logs on Windows AD or the syslog equivalent on Linux).